# Show multiple menu output joomla

Tags: joomla, menu

I am running a website on Joomla and have a certain plugin installed.

I can make a special menu item which refers to this plugin to show data from a source, however this is quite limited.

I now need to make 5 different menu items while I actually just want to have 1 menu item which shows all.

is it possible to combine the output of multiple joomla menu items on one page (with one click)?

To make it less confusing, an example:

1. Menu item 1
2. Menu item 2
3. Menu item 3

I want the output of each menu item shown in 1 single page.

1. Menu item-all items

Comment: The question is confusing .. one menu item is one page. Are you saying you want something similar to a blog layout where you have multiple content items brought together to make a single page?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing question. I think you could say it like that. However, unfortunatelly it's not a native Joomla content item but generated by a plugin. This plugin creates some kind of categories but I can only show 1 category per menu-item (1 category per page). I have a total of 10 categories which I want to show the output on one page.

Comment: I don't know how a plugin could create a Joomla category. Do you mean a component? When you say not native do you mean that it is not part of the core CMS or do you mean it is not a Joomla extension at all?

Comment: I used the wrong term. I am using a Joomla extension which manages my Joomla category and articles (in a different way). This extensions provides me with a specific menu item to show a list of articles belonging to a certain category. However, this men item is limited to display onecategory only. I need to create 10 different menu items, each for displaying one category.

I know this sounds easy to do with the native Joomla blog layout, but this extension does more than only showing article content etc. So my question is, how can I show the output of 10 menu items in 1 page with 1 menu click?

Comment: You can't, you need to either modify the component or ask the developer of the component to modify it or if the developer takes code from users you could work out how to modify it and share the code. You can probably do it in the same way that the core handles it.

Comment: Well, the developer said he is not going to modify the code. I am now experimenting with a work-around: I make 10 menu-items but make them invisible for the user. I make another menu-item with Itemid=XX, I hardcode in the template that if($_GET['Itemid'] == "XX") a jquery will run to import all data from seperate menu-items, strip out unnecessary html tags (such as <html> and <body>) so only the content is left and display this in the page.

The only downside I have so far is that jquery takes some time to load..so the user won't see content on the page for about 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: What I might do instead is put them in modules and load those. But the cool thing about open source is that you can fix it.